# Editor html formatting is different from view source

Tags: tinymce, html

Here's what I see when I click on the HTML tab in the editor...

```
<div style="margin: 10px 0;"><a href="test.jpg" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">
<img style="float: left; margin: 10px; max-width: 25%;" title="test" src="test.jpg" alt="test" />
</a><a href="test" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">
<img title="PDF file" src="test.png" alt="PDF file" />
<span style="font-weight: bold; text-transform: capitalize;">Test ...</span>
</a>
<span>test <strong>test</strong> test? test, test, i.e., </span>
<a href="test.pdf" rel="nofollow" target="_blank"> ... Get Content Here</a>

</div>
```

And here's what I see when I look at view source in Chrome and FF:

```
<div style="margin: 10px 0;">
        <a href="test.jpg" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><br />
            <img style="float: left; margin: 10px; max-width: 25%;" title="test" src="test.jpg" alt="test" /><br />
        </a></p>
<p>
            <a href="test" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><br />
                <img title="PDF file" src="test.png" alt="PDF file" /><br />
                <span style="font-weight: bold; text-transform: capitalize;">Test &#8230;</span><br />
            </a><br />
            <span>test <strong>test</strong> test? test, test, i.e., </span><br />
            <a href="test.pdf" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"> &#8230; Get Content Here</a>
        </p>
</p></div>
```

Any ideas what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're referring to all the paragraph tags, those are coming from [`wpautop`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop). You can either disable it or write around it...many chose to just disable it, especially those who are particular about content display.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is being parsed by the Apache web-server. That's why it appears different once it's viewed in your browser.